# Javascript same addeventlistener for more than one elements

Tags: javascript

I am working with `addeventlistener` to create events and dynamically adding removing class name too. This is my code. Am getting expected result for first text box but not the next where i am wrong.

```
<html>  
  <style>
    .test5 {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      outline: none;
    }
  </style>  
  <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test1">
      <div class="test7" id="test">test</div>
      <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test2">
    </form>      
    <script>
      function gettext() {
        var val = this.className += " test5";
        console.log(val);
      }
      function gettexts() {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('ids').classList.remove('test5');
      }
      var get = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');
      //for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
        //get[i].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
        //get[i].addEventListener('blur', gettexts, false);
        get[0].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
        get[0].addEventListener('blur', gettexts, false);
      //}
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique.

Comment: Use class for several elements. ID is supposed to be unique.

Comment: Also I for once strongly suggest using jQuery which will make your life so much easier

Comment: Ok if i use unique id how can i pass ID dynamiccally to the funciton gettext() and gettexts() so that i can reuse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
        function focus() {

            var val = this.className = "test5";
            console.log(val);
        }

        function blur() {
            this.className = "test1";
        }
        var get = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
            get[i].addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
            get[i].addEventListener('blur', blur, false);

        }

    </script>
    <style>
    .test5
    {
        color:Red;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: what is your actual need? what do you want to do e=with gettexts() function?

Comment: If i click first text box it should create new class(test5) and once i click second text box class(test5) should be removed from fisrt text box and it should added to next one. This is what am expecting can you help

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the event object inside your event handler to access the affected element:

```
function gettext(event) {
  event.target.className += 'test5';
  console.log(event.target);
}

var get = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');
for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
  get[i].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
}
```

Also by using event delegation you don't need to assign the event handler to all inputs, but just to a common ancestor (e.g. the document or a surrounding div):

```
function gettext(event) {
  if (event.target && event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT') {
    event.target.className += 'test5';
    console.log(event.target);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('focus', gettext, true); // EDIT: Oops, the third parameter needs to true for this to work
```

EDIT: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/88DnZ/

Also: if you just want to change the style of an input element on focus, there is no need to use JavaScript. Just use CSS:

```
input:focus {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

First suggestion: please use jquery;

Second, before you do somenthing you must wait the page load event;

Third, do not put code inside body ... !;

If I understand what you whant this is the code:

```
<html>
    <style>
      .test5{
        border: 1px solid #000;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
     function gettext() {
        var val = this.className += " test5";
        console.log(val);
    }

    function gettexts() {
        var val1 = document.getElementById('ids').classList.remove('test5');
    }


    window.onload = function(){
            var get = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');
        //for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {
            //get[i].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
            //get[i].addEventListener('blur', gettexts, false);
            get[0].addEventListener('focus', gettext, false);
            get[0].addEventListener('blur', gettexts, false);
        //}
    }

    </script>
    <body>
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test1">
      <div class="test7" id="test">test</div>
      <input type="text" id="ids" class="test1" value="test2">
    </form>

    <script>


    </script>
    </body>
    <html>
```

That's all folks!